# Remove lines where the 10th column contains empty fields in text file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a huge tab-delimited text file with 10 columns. Now I want to delete all rows from the file that contain no value in column 10.

For example:

```
a b c d e f g h i j
4 6 8 9 4 2 1 6 4 2
1 5 9 8 5 1 8 3 6 
1 6 8 5 4 7 7 9 4 7
4 5 8 9 9 2 1 8 4 
3 4 7 5 8 8 2 5 3 6
```

Expected output:

```
a b c d e f g h i j
4 6 8 9 4 2 1 6 4 2
1 6 8 5 4 7 7 9 4 7
3 4 7 5 8 8 2 5 3 6
```

I would like to use something like:

```
awk '$10 == ""' print $0 file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command was almost there. You can try this:

```
awk '$10 != "" {print}' file
```

- `$10 != ""` This tests if the 10th field is not empty
- `print` prints the entire line

Answer (score 2):

You can print each line where col 10 isn't empty using

```
awk '{if ($10) print}' file.txt
```

---

```
$ cat file.txt
a b c d e f g h i j
4 6 8 9 4 2 1 6 4 2
1 5 9 8 5 1 8 3 6
1 6 8 5 4 7 7 9 4 7
4 5 8 9 9 2 1 8 4
3 4 7 5 8 8 2 5 3 6
$
$
$ awk '{if ($10) print}' file.txt
a b c d e f g h i j
4 6 8 9 4 2 1 6 4 2
1 6 8 5 4 7 7 9 4 7
3 4 7 5 8 8 2 5 3 6
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed it using a "simple" `grep`:

```
grep $'.\t.\t.\t.\t.\t.\t.\t.\t.\t.' file.txt
```

The `'.'` stands for any character, the `\t` for a TAB character.

Answer (score 0):

how about something simpler (if you care to do $1=$1) ?

```
 mawk  'NF*=9<NF'
                  or
 mawk 'NF*=10==NF'
```

or *even simpler than that* (if you don't care about $1=$1)

```
 mawk NF==10      # shell-quoting optional for this one
                  or
 mawk '9<NF'

a b c d e f g h i j
4 6 8 9 4 2 1 6 4 2
1 6 8 5 4 7 7 9 4 7
3 4 7 5 8 8 2 5 3 6
```

or even thoroughly counter-intuitive but fully posix-compliant forms :

```
mawk '+RS==NF%10'
```

Don't spend time manually checking `$10` when up-front field splitting along already has done that on your behalf